# Abrir nova tela com as opções do usuário clicado

Tags: android, listview

Tenho uma listView e nela coloquei todos os usuários do banco, uso um adapterView para pegar a posição e o id, porém não sei como irei abrir uma nova tela para as opções avançadas para cada usuário.

segue o código

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
      .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
      setContentView(R.layout.list);
      listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
      accessWebService();

      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
             public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                 int position, long id) {
               // When clicked, show a toast with the TextView text
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView) view).getText(),
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
           });

     }
```

Teria que vincular algum atributo identificador no item para pega-lo, ou posso fazer tudo com Json?

Comment: ele está em um banco local? Ou vem de um webservice?

Comment: vem de um webservice no apache

Comment: Então, acho que vc terá que passar o ID deste usuário para e lá (através de outra requisição) pegar os dados do servidor através do ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
listDebitosPendentes.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetalhesDebitosActivity.class);

                  //Passa para a activity o id no banco de dados
                  intent.putExtra("ID", id);

                  startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
```

Na outra **activity** você pega da seguinte forma.

```
 Long idSelected = getIntent().getLongExtra("ID", 0);
```

No meu caso eu faço uma query pegando por esse ID.

```
int id = Integer.valueOf(idSelected.toString());

debitosPendentes = debitoPendentesDao.queryForId(id);
```